# Logic behind CAD apps multi-selection and alignment functionality

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas, paperjs

I am trying to build a small CAD app using HTML5 Canvas and [Paper.js](http://paperjs.org)

Now I am stuck at a problem I'd hate asking for help for since I believe I should solve this on my own, but everytime I try to think about a solution my head hurts.

### I am trying to build the following functions:

- **Align-left**
- **Align-right**
- **Align-center.**

The user is supposed to select a bunch of elements on the canvas and click one of the above functions to align them together.

The whole concept is that the user selects a *Reference Item* in a way. The elements are aligned relative-to the Reference Item. This ensures that the alignments happen in a user predictable way.

### There are 2 ways for the user to select elements

- **Selection-via-Intersection**

> The user clicks and drags a *selection rectangle*. While dragging I
>   can track in an array which items *intersected* with the selection
>   rectangle. I can track the first intersected item here just fine, so I
>   have a *Reference Item* .Works perfectly so far.

- **Selection-via-Click+Shift**

> The user holds Shift and clicks on elements to do a multi-selection.
>   It's a functionality I'm sure everyone has seen in any modern graphics
>   editor. I have yet to figure out a way how to track a first-selected
>   item here, since items can be set as first-selected and then
>   deselected.

### The problem:

**The above selection methods can be COMBINED together -**

**The user can select-via-intersection and then start select/de-select items using Shift+Click.**

**Which one from the selectedItems is the *Reference-Item* now?**

**An example:**

> Item 2 was the first-selection on selection-via-intersection. Item 2
>   was de-selected using Shift+Click. Which one is the *Reference-Item
>   now?*.

Here is a GIF that illustrates what I am talking about (although it's invinsible in the GIF the items get selected as soon as the *intersection rectangle touches them*.)

[image]

I am aware that the whole thing will involve some array logic but I cannot seem to grasp how to implement the whole thing.

### Notes:

Apart from the complexity of this thing, I have performance constraints as well. Intersection Detection which is used for the Selection-via-Intersection is already a heavy operation and it get's fired continously while the user drags a selection rectangle.

This is the code for Select-Via-Intersection

The following function `getSortedIntersects` get's called continuously while the user drags a selection rectangle. I log in the console the first selected item:

```
    var checkedSegments = new Array();

    function getSortedIntersects(rect) {

//children are all the items drawn on the canvas
        var children = project.activeLayer.children;
//I clone the children array into another array and I exclude all items other than Paths
//Intersection Detection works only on paths.
        var pathsOnCanvas = children.filter(function (el) {
            return el instanceof Path
        });
        var newCheckedSegments = new Array();
        var firstSelection = "";
        //Start looping over all Paths on the canvas
        for (var i = 0; i < pathsOnCanvas.length; i++) {

            //create an array which lists all the intersections. The array is called ''intersections''
            var intersections = pathsOnCanvas[i].getIntersections(rect);


            //If there is at least 1 intersection OR the rect contains a path then proceed
            if (intersections.length > 0 || rect.contains(pathsOnCanvas[i].bounds)) {

                //Checks if the selected item at index i is in the newSegments array. If so, it continues iterating the loop without going further at this iteration.
                if (newCheckedSegments.indexOf(pathsOnCanvas[i]) >= 0)
                    continue;


                pathsOnCanvas[i].selected = true;
                newCheckedSegments.push(pathsOnCanvas[i]); 
            }
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < newCheckedSegments.length; i++) {
            if (checkedSegments.indexOf(newCheckedSegments[i]) < 0)
                checkedSegments.push(newCheckedSegments[i]);
            firstSelection = (checkedSegments[0].id);
            console.log("first selection is " + firstSelection);
        }

        for (var i = checkedSegments.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (newCheckedSegments.indexOf(checkedSegments[i]) < 0) {

                checkedSegments[i].selected = false;
                checkedSegments.splice(i, 1);


            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: As a user i wouldn't like the logic of 'the align will occur on the first selection'. Not that predictable, especially... with the click shift. Rather, i'd like that, when clicking on an align button, the cursor changes, and when i clic on a segment all selected segments will align on it with current align setting. If you still want this logic, i can suggest a way to implement it. But it's more an interface issue than an algorithmic one : you cannot code it because you would have a hard time explaining the logic : the user won't understand either.

Comment: Indeed it is. I already started going the direction you suggest. But what is the way to implement the above? Just out of curiosity and maybe it helps someone else who stumbles upon this.

Comment: For the ways to align, i guess youtube is your friend 'CAD align' or like could give you other idea (although mine seems fine). For the algorithm, You need basically a queue which allows to remove an inner item (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type ) Btw, when seeing your code i think you'd have great advantage to build such higher order structures to ease your work. But i don't feel like answering for an hypothetical need :-) Happy coding to you !

Comment: @GameAlchemist I'd rather figure out my own way for alignment other than youtube. I guess I am gonna be thinking lots about the centers of elemenents and their x,y positions. Thanks for the tip and thanks for the link.

Comment: @GameAlchemist I just finished the thing. You saved me from a lot of unnecessary pain. Thanks again. Beer is on you

Comment: Glad i could help. Hurra for the beer ! :-)